# some . . . some . . . still some

Tags: quantifiers

Are all the following combinations of quantifiers correct?

> a. People have different skin colors. **Some** are yellow, **some** are white, and **some** are black.

> b. People have  different skin colors. **Some** are yellow, **some** are white, and **still some** are black.

> c. People have  different skin colors. **Some** are yellow, **some** are white, and **others** are black.

> d. People have  different skin colors. **Some** are yellow, **others** are white, and **still others** are black.

Comment: *Still some* is always wrong in this context.  *Still* is always used with *others* in this kind of construction.

Comment: Thank you. Do you find the other sentences okay?

Answer (score 1):

All your examples are grammatical and understandable. But some are more idiomatic than others

Example b strikes me as quite odd. According to Ngram, “still some” and “still others” are acceptable, but the great deficiency in Ngram is that it ignores context. I doubt that in the context of a simple list “still some” is idiomatic. I cannot, however, cite an authority to support that assertion.

Examples a, c, and d are certainly idiomatic. In terms of style, example a is parallel but repetitive. Example c seems to sacrifice parallelism without eliminating repetition. Example d is better than c at eliminating repetition. Although you do not mention this option, “still yet others” provides even greater variety.

Recommendations about style are matters of opinion. Example a has the merit of not encouraging an inference that this is anything more than a list. With such a basic list, however, parallelism is probably not needed to clarify your intended thought, and example d has the merit of being less boring to read. It is up to you which choice you prefer.